# Ignore Group if LIMIT is not reached in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am working on a rather tricky SQL for my level of knowledge. I have searched and searched for an answer but haven't came across anything. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

How can you stop SQL from outputting group of rows if the limit set is not reached?

For example -

**Data**

```
Fruits  Ordered  Date
Orange  4        2015-05-01
Orange  2        2015-05-01
Orange  20       2015-05-01
Apple   30       2015-05-02
Apple   40       2015-05-02
Apple   24       2015-05-02   
Apple   19       2015-05-02   
Apple   22       2015-05-02
```

From the data I would like to select and group by Date, but only have a LIMIT of 5.

If there isn't five rows in that group, I want SQL to ignore that group.

So If I did a SUM of all ordered values for each Date Group and SQL ignored the group that didn't consist of 5 values the desired results would look like the following

**Desired Result**

```
Fruits  SUM(Ordered)  Date
Apple   117           2015-05-02
```

Hope this makes sense, please ask any questions if required!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [having](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) clause to filter out the groups you don't need, keeping only the groups where there are more than 4 dates:

```
SELECT Fruits, SUM(Ordered), Date
FROM table
GROUP BY Date
HAVING COUNT(Date) > 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Fruits,sum(Ordered),Date from Table
group by Fruits, Date
where Fruits in (select Fruits from Table 
      group by Fruits having count(*) >= 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    Fruits, SUM(Ordered), Date
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t ti WHERE ti.Fruits = t.Fruits) < 5 THEN Ordered END As gID
    FROM t) dt
GROUP BY
    Fruits, gID
```

Actually you need to use your `PK` column instead of `Ordered` in the `CASE` like this:

```
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t ti WHERE ti.Fruits = t.Fruits) < 5 THEN `PK` END As gID
```